# Computed column 'Month' in table cannot be persisted because the column is non-deterministic

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am getting one error when I try to make my field IsPersisted=True

This is the definition of my table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AdvanceMST](
[AdvanceID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[AppliedDate] [datetime] NULL,
[ApprovedDate] [datetime] NULL,
[AdvanceStatus] [varchar](100) NULL,
[AdvanceFromEngineerID] [bigint] NULL,
[AdvanceToEngineerID] [bigint] NULL,
[AccountResourceID] [bigint] NULL,
[AdvanceAmount] [float] NULL,
[ApprovedAdvanceAmount] [float] NULL,
[POrderID] [bigint] NULL,
[SiteID] [bigint] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_AdvanceMST] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[AdvanceID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,     ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

This is the error message
Computed column 'Month' in table 'Tmp_AdvanceMST' cannot be persisted because the column is non-deterministic.

I am not able to understand what does this error message mean and how to solve this problem in order to make it IsPersisted=true

Comment: The error message is for Tmp_AdvanceMST. Code is for AdvanceMST.

Comment: Please give the definition of the `Month` column you are attempting to add!

Comment: This is the definition of my month column..(datename(month,[AppliedDate]))

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `datename` function can return different results dependant on the language of the logged in user hence is not deterministic. Marking a computed column as persisted means SQL Server stores the results of the computation which requires there to be exactly one result.

If you need this as persisted at all you can replace with a 12 branch `case` expression with the specific language you want used.

Although it would probably be all round better to have `month(AppliedDate)` as a persisted integer column and have the `datename` function in a non persisted computed column.

**Edited to give example as per comments**

```
CREATE TABLE #T
  (
     [AppliedDate] DATETIME,
     [Month] AS CASE MONTH([AppliedDate])
          WHEN 1 THEN 'January'
          WHEN 2 THEN 'February'
          WHEN 3 THEN 'March'
          WHEN 4 THEN 'April'
          WHEN 5 THEN 'May'
          WHEN 6 THEN 'June'
          WHEN 7 THEN 'July'
          WHEN 8 THEN 'August'
          WHEN 9 THEN 'September'
          WHEN 10 THEN 'October'
          WHEN 11 THEN 'November'
          WHEN 12 THEN 'December'
        END PERSISTED
  )  

  INSERT INTO #T([AppliedDate]) VALUES (GETDATE())
```

Comment: Please elaborate what do you mean by "datename function can return different results dependant on the language of the logged in user hence is not deterministic."

Comment: `SET LANGUAGE Italian; SELECT DATENAME(month, getdate());SET LANGUAGE us_english;SELECT DATENAME(month,  getdate())`

Comment: You can use a `CASE` expression as previously suggested `CASE MONTH([AppliedDate]) WHEN 1 THEN 'January' WHEN 2 THEN 'February'
END`

Comment: ..Still not getting clear idea..Can you please edit your answer as per your suggestions????