# Formatted local time in a virtual generated column of SQLite

Tags: sqlite

I want to store date in milliseconds, but also I want to see the formatted representation of it.
In order to not waste the drive space it makes sense to use a virtual generated column for this.

I wrote it:

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS example;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS example (
    time INTEGER,
    formatted_time GENERATED ALWAYS AS (strftime('%Y.%m.%d %H:%m', time/1000, 'unixepoch')) VIRTUAL
);
INSERT INTO example (time) VALUES (1605960000000);
INSERT INTO example (time) VALUES (1615413202000);
```

It works, but I can't set the second modifier of `strftime(format,timestring,modifier,modifier...)` to get the local time. (It returns UTC time by default.)

When I use:

```sql
formatted_time GENERATED ALWAYS AS (strftime('%Y.%m.%d %H:%m', time/1000, 'unixepoch', 'localtime')) VIRTUAL
```

It throws `Result: non-deterministic use of strftime() in a generated column` when I insert a data.

While it works as expected:

```sql
select strftime('%Y.%m.%d %H:%m', 1615413202000/1000, 'unixepoch', 'localtime');
```

---

How to create a virtual column with formatted **local** time?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating generate column based on today's date in SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66298208/creating-generate-column-based-on-todays-date-in-sqlite)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's [not possible](https://www.sqlite.org/deterministic.html#special_case_processing_for_date_time_functions).

Based on this answers:

- [Creating generate column based on today's date in SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66300577/11468937)
- [Computed column 'Month' in table cannot be persisted because the column is non-deterministic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7315610/11468937)

SQLite requires to the value of a generated column would be the same on any machine in any time zone (be **deterministic**). Even  for a **virtual** generated column.

In my case for `time` value `1615413202000` the `formatted_time` would be different for the same table opened in different time zones, so the the table would be "non-deterministic".

---

As a workaround it possible to create a [view](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createview.html#description):

```sql
CREATE VIEW example_view AS
SELECT time, strftime('%Y.%m.%d %H:%m', time/1000, 'unixepoch', 'localtime') as formatted_time_local
FROM example;
```

*(based on [Shawn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66300577/11468937))*